# TalkBack and Firefox fails when select options are over 20

Tags: android, html, firefox, accessibility, talkback

So I am using Android S3 4.1.2 and S4 using 4.2.2 and the latest versions of talkback and firefox. I have a simple html select with a Date of Birth selection that goes from 1996 to 1900. When talkback is enabled and navigates through the page. It reads the collapsed combo box correctly, but then reads each year after the 20th option as another combo box.

It's pretty basic HTML, is there some magic trick I need to do to get TalkBack to read old school HTML because iOS voiceover reads it normally. Talkback seems to fail on any select list that contains more than 20 options.

```
<label for="dobDayCL" class="dobPicker">Please select the day you were born.</label> 
<select name="dobDay" id="dobDay" tabindex="4" size="1">
<option selected="" value="" role="option" aria-selected="true">Day</option>
<option value="1" role="option" aria-selected="false">1</option>
<option value="2" role="option" aria-selected="false">2</option>
<option value="3" role="option" aria-selected="false">3</option>
<option value="4" role="option" aria-selected="false">4</option>
<option value="5" role="option" aria-selected="false">5</option>
<option value="6" role="option" aria-selected="false">6</option>
<option value="7" role="option" aria-selected="false">7</option>
<option value="8" role="option" aria-selected="false">8</option>
<option value="9" role="option" aria-selected="false">9</option>
<option value="10" role="option" aria-selected="false">10</option>
<option value="11" role="option" aria-selected="false">11</option>
<option value="12" role="option" aria-selected="false">12</option>
<option value="13" role="option" aria-selected="false">13</option>
<option value="14" role="option" aria-selected="false">14</option>
<option value="15" role="option" aria-selected="false">15</option>
<option value="16" role="option" aria-selected="false">16</option>
<option value="17" role="option" aria-selected="false">17</option>
<option value="18" role="option" aria-selected="false">18</option>
<option value="19" role="option" aria-selected="false">19</option>
<option value="20" role="option" aria-selected="false">20</option>
<option value="21" role="option" aria-selected="false">21</option>
<option value="22" role="option" aria-selected="false">22</option>
<option value="23" role="option" aria-selected="false">23</option>
<option value="24" role="option" aria-selected="false">24</option>
<option value="25" role="option" aria-selected="false">25</option>
<option value="26" role="option" aria-selected="false">26</option>
<option value="27" role="option" aria-selected="false">27</option>
<option value="28" role="option" aria-selected="false">28</option>
<option value="29" role="option" aria-selected="false">29</option>
<option value="30" role="option" aria-selected="false">30</option>
<option value="31" role="option" aria-selected="false">31</option>
</select>
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why?

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers? Like Chrome, Dolphin HD etc to see if this is a Firefox issue or an Android/Talkback issue?

Comment: I cannot tell you why, but passed this onto two people who work on the browser.